# How should I change the size of my tiles?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been looking through the new unity tilemap system.

I've basically edited the example for a tile given here: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/2d-extras/blob/master/Assets/Tilemap/Tiles/Terrain%20Tile/Scripts/TerrainTile.cs

I have implimented my own tilemap, except my tiles are too small. This is a prett basic question I guess but I cant work out how to make them bigger.

This is what I've gotten so far

[image: This is what I've gotten so far]

The code is mostly the same as the example project I linked above.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you want to get some help here, you have to give us more than a link, a screenshot and a question.

Comment: Is the link to someone else's code? Please share what you've tried and what research you've looked at.

Comment: Please don't include notes like "thanks in advanced[sic]" in questions. See [no thanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into your import settings for your sprites and lower the number of pixels per unit it should do the trick. I hope this helps!